# OnEnterCollision2D and OnExitCollision2D not working Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

[image]

As you can see in the picture the cube still collides with the block but in the console, you can see a message that says false. That is the isGrounded variable. I can't jump because the isGrounded is false. This is the code script attached to the cube:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Cube1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float jumpForce = 7.0f;
    private bool isGrounded = true;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private AudioSource audio;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (isGrounded && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButton(0)))
        {
            audio.Play();

            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);

            Debug.Log("Works");

            isGrounded = false;
        }

        Debug.Log(isGrounded);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground") || other.gameObject.CompareTag("Block"))
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }

        string collider = other.gameObject.name;

        if (collider == "leftCollider" || collider == "rightCollider" || collider == "bottomCollider" || other.gameObject.CompareTag("Spike") || other.gameObject.CompareTag("Thorn"))
        {
            GameOver();
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Block"))
        {
            isGrounded = false;
        }
    }

    public void GameOver()
    {
        if (MyVariables.highScore < (int)MyVariables.score)
        {
            MyVariables.highScore = (int)MyVariables.score;
        }
        MyVariables.score = 0;
        MyVariables.obstacleCount = 0;
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are checking for if the tag of the block is both colliding with the tag of "Ground" as well as with the tag of "Block" but in the game the player object is only colliding with one of the tags and isn't setting the isGrounded to true as you can see where you call the OnCollisionEnter function
rather checking for if the player is colliding with the tag "Ground" and the tag "block" you would need to check for one or the other as you can see below

```
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
{
    isGrounded = true;
}
```

alternatively you could also use a boxcast which extends downward as a ground checker in order to check if you are touching the box which can work better if you are concerned about the program accidentally setting isGrounded = true when your player touches the side of a Ground object like as is shown below

```
private bool IsGrounded()
{
      return Physics2D.CapsuleCast(coll.bounds.center, coll.bounds.size, 
      0f, 0, Vector2.down, .1f, Ground);
}
```

the program above will check if the player has ground directly below them by creating a boxcast directly underneath them and then checking every frame for if that box is overlapping a gameobject which is tagged with the ground tag